# I have written a MYSQL procedure and there is mistake in syntax, can't figure out the correct syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedures

The MYSQL procedure will
1. Create TABLE1_ARCHIVE similar to TABLE1 if it is not there.
2.Insert the values from the TABLE1 into TABLE1_ARCHIVE based on date condition
3. Delete those records from TABLE1.

Link to the code:
https://paiza.io/projects/Eq7I5YGo-lt7_gu8wpQNdg?language=mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_EVENTS ( IN f_table VARCHAR(255),
                                IN t_table VARCHAR(255),
                                IN t_ts TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    DECLARE c_sql VARCHAR(255);
     DECLARE i_sql VARCHAR(255);
     DECLARE d_sql VARCHAR(255);    

SET @c_sql = CONCAT(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', @t_table , ' LIKE ', @f_table );
PREPARE stmt FROM  @c_sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;

SET @i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', @t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', @f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <=  ', @t_ts);
PREPARE stmt FROM  @i_sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;

COMMIT;

SET @d_sql = CONCAT(' DELETE FROM ', @f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ', @t_ts);
PREPARE stmt FROM  @d_sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;
COMMIT;
END;

CALL ARCHIVE_EVENTS ('TABLE1', 'TABLE1_ARCHIVE', now());
```

---

After doing the changes, the procedure looks like this and is still not working :

The error that i am getting is

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_EVENTS (IN f_table VARCHAR(255),IN t_table VARCHAR(255),IN t_ts TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    DECLARE c_sql VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE i_sql VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE d_sql VARCHAR(255);    

    SET c_sql = CONCAT(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', t_table , ' LIKE ', f_table);
    PREPARE stmt FROM  c_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt ;

    SET i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ', t_ts);
    PREPARE stmt FROM  i_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt ;

    COMMIT;

    SET d_sql = CONCAT(' DELETE FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ', t_ts);
    PREPARE stmt FROM  d_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt ;
    COMMIT;
END;

CALL ARCHIVE_EVENTS ('TEST', 'TEST_ARCHIVE', now());
```

Comment: "I have written a MYSQL procedure and getting the following error ! Not sure if the syntax is correct"  i don't see a error in the question.

Comment: You are confusing '@'variables declared variables and parameters. @f_table is a different variable to f_table. All your '@'variables will contain null.

Comment: Also adding to @P.Salmon 's comment also this approach opens you up to SQL injections without validating variables t_table and f_table are real table names (use information schema and `EXECUTE USING .. (prevents SQL injection)` and IF statements to check  if the table exists before executing the CREATE/INSERT/DELETE queries).,    To use `EXECUTE ... USING ...` to prevent SQL injections see a example here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html .. If you can't figure it out ask a new question.

Comment: @P.Salmon , let me correct the syntax and check it once. I will post the error as well. I have missed to include the exception that i got while executing this procedure.

Comment: @P.Salmon still getting the same exception. Added the exception that i got as well.

Comment: @RaymondNijland , thanks for the suggestion and the link. I can look at it later once this procedure starts working. I have added the exception as well. Can you look at it and suggest what changes has to be done.

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/Eq7I5YGo-lt7_gu8wpQNdg?language=mysql

Answer (score 1):

It isn't difficult to debug a procedure like this just put in a few select statements. Note @variables have to be used in the prepared statements and you have not quoted the date t_ts. And possibly you have not set delimiters.

```
    drop procedure if exists p;
    delimiter $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE p (IN f_table VARCHAR(255),IN t_table VARCHAR(255),IN t_ts TIMESTAMP)
    BEGIN

    SET @c_sql = (select CONCAT(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', t_table , ' LIKE ', f_table));
    select @c_sql;

    /*PREPARE stmt FROM  @c_sql;
        EXECUTE stmt ;
         deallocate prepare stmt;
    */   
    SET @i_sql = (select CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ',char(39), t_ts,char(39)));
    select @i_sql;
    /*
    PREPARE stmt FROM  @i_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt ;
    deallocate prepare stmt;

    COMMIT;
    */
    SET @d_sql = (select CONCAT(' DELETE FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ', char(39),t_ts, char(39)));
    select @d_sql;
    /*
    PREPARE stmt FROM  @d_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt ;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
    COMMIT;
    */
END $$
delimiter ;
drop table users_copy;
CALL p('users', 'users_copy', now());

Yield these statements
+---------------------------------------------------+
| @c_sql                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_copy LIKE users |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @i_sql                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  INSERT INTO users_copy SELECT * FROM users WHERE `event_date` <= '2018-05-09 19:36:54' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| @d_sql                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  DELETE FROM users WHERE `event_date` <= '2018-05-09 19:36:54' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

You could then test each of them if you wished or uncomment the prepared statements and let rip.

Comment: Individual queries are working absolutely fine even for me. But i have to run this procedure in loop. So i have to make sure when the procedure runs it executes these queries along. When i tried to execute the queries after the changes suggested by @Kesav . I got the following exeption:

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00' at line 1

Comment: CALL ARCHIVE_EVENTS ('TEST', 'TEST_ARCHIVE', TIMESTAMP('2018-05-10 00:00:00'));

Comment: @kesav does not wrap t_ts in single quotes so I'm not really surprised.

Comment: SET @i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ', t_ts);  -> What change do i need to do here ? I did not get your point, sorry

Comment: SET @i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ',char(39), t_ts,char(39));  -> this worked, got it

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ARCHIVE_EVENTS;
CREATE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_EVENTS (IN f_table CHAR(100),IN t_table 
CHAR(100),IN t_ts TIMESTAMP)
READS SQL DATA
COMMENT 'Test'
BEGIN

SET @c_sql = CONCAT(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', t_table , ' LIKE ', f_table);
PREPARE stmt FROM  @c_sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;

SET @i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `dateTime` <= ', DATE(t_ts));
PREPARE stmt1 FROM  @i_sql;
EXECUTE stmt1 ;

COMMIT;

SET @d_sql = CONCAT(' DELETE FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `dateTime` <= ', DATE(t_ts));
PREPARE stmt2 FROM  @d_sql;
EXECUTE stmt2 ;
COMMIT;
END;

CALL ARCHIVE_EVENTS ('TEST', 'WS_REL_TEST', now());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't just dump your code in your answer, try to describe a little bit what is your solution. Pleas take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: use this link for the minified working version of the above code. [link]http://rextester.com/ORIL14490

Comment: SET @i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE event_date <= ',char(39), t_ts,char(39));   there is one correction and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_EVENTS (IN f_table CHAR(100),IN t_table 
CHAR(100),IN t_ts TIMESTAMP)

BEGIN

SET @c_sql = CONCAT(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', t_table , ' LIKE ', f_table);

SET @i_sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ', t_table, ' SELECT * FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ',char(39), t_ts,char(39));

SET @d_sql = CONCAT(' DELETE FROM ', f_table, ' WHERE `event_date` <= ',char(39), t_ts,char(39));

PREPARE stmt FROM  @c_sql;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM  @i_sql;
PREPARE stmt2 FROM  @d_sql;


EXECUTE stmt ;
EXECUTE stmt1 ;
EXECUTE stmt2 ;
COMMIT;

END;
```

This is the working code, thanks to the above answers. This is the final solution for the query that worked for me.